# carmichael numbers - where to start studying and understanding them

Tags: calculus, carmichael-numbers

I'm pretty new to Carmichael numbers and only know the basics. I'm in AP Calculus BC currently and I chose Carmichael numbers to write a 4000-word paper on for my school. I want to learn Carmichael numbers and write a paper on regarding RSA encryption - I have to argue a certain topic. How do I start learning Carmichael numbers for someone with rudimentary Calc 2 skills.

I tried to start reading this paper, but some of the notation is far too confusing for me: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.06963.pdf.

Could I get some advice and/or resources to start? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by understanding as much as you can of the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number .

Then start checking out the external references there. Some are to popular expositions, some are to serious research papers.

At each stage, try to extend your knowledge while thinking about what you can fit into your paper. Steer between diving in over your head with technical mathematics and simply reporting what you read without absorbing it.

There's lots to say about Carmichael numbers without even touching on RSA encryption. Trying to combine them in one 4000 word paper might be a mistake.